# Regular expression matching variable at end of string

Tags: python-3.x, regex, string, list-comprehension, python-3.12

I have some histograms in a `.root` file which are called `"Name/NameEvent1Ch0"`, `"Name/NameEvent1Ch1"`... `"Name/NameEvent1Ch31"` ... `"Name/NameEvent2Ch0"`... `"Name/NameEvent{x}Ch32"`...

I want to create two lists, which match the characters after `Ch`, the last characters in the string. All the histograms of channels in `x_channels` should go into `analogues_x` and the others should go into `analogues_y`.

When there was only one moving part, that is when the strings were only named for the channel and not the event (`Name/NameCh{0-31}`) it was easy, I just did `analogues_x = [root_file.Get(f"Target/TargetCh{ch}") for ch in x_channels]`. Now that there's another variable I don't know how to do this in the most efficient way.

I'm extremely inexpert in regular expressions but it seems like this might be the way forward?

The following code:

```
x_channels = [8,7,9,6,10,5,11,4,12,3,13,2,14,1,15,0]
y_channels = [27,28,26,29,25,30,24,31,23,16,22,17,21,18,20,19]
analogues_x = [root_file.Get(re.compile(rf"Ch{ch}")) for ch in x_channels]
```

Gives me the error:

```
TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation
```

Edit: I was asked to make it clearer what the input was and what the desired output was so:
The input variable is a .root file. It contains histograms which you access using `root_file.Get("name_of_my_histogram")`. The histograms are named "histoevent1ch0", "histoevent1ch1", ... "histoevent19ch31", where 19 is not really 19 but is some number. I want to select all of the histograms that end with numbers in x_channels and put them in one list, and all of the histograms ending with numbers in y_channls and put them in another list.

I hope that's clear enough

Comment: Can you edit your question and show the clear input variable, and then point out what the _exact_ output is which you want to get?

Comment: The input variable is a .root file. It contains histograms which you access using `root_file.Get("name_of_my_histogram")`. The histograms are named "histoevent1ch0", "histoevent1ch1", ... "histoevent19ch31", where 19 is not really 19 but is some number. I want to select all of the histograms that end with numbers in `x_channels` and put them in one list, and all of the histograms ending with numbers in `y_channls` and put them in another list. Is that clearer?

Comment: Does the `root_file.Get()` API allow you to use regex at all? Did you see the docs? Where can we see them?

Comment: I had no idea that it was possibile that it didn’t allow regex. I guess here https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/classTFile.html you can find all the documentation relating to a TFile, I think in particular the Get method is this one but I’m not sure https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/classTDirectoryFile.html#aee65615b0bc6f8ec09c34a785d0350fd